# ASP.NET Core MVC accept list from user and update database records that match that list

Tags: sql-server, excel, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

We're moving from MS Access VBA to ASP.NET MVC (I know, big jump). One thing we could do in MS Access is paste a list of items into a temp table and then update records in a database based on that list. I'm having trouble determining the best way to go about this in ASP.NET Core.

For example, we have a database of products and users routinely go in to an application and make a comment on a product regarding is supply chain availability. Sometimes, users are provided a list (excel) of products from a supplier with updates for each product that they want to enter into the database. I'd like for them to be able to mass upload those comments, rather than entering them one by one.

I've looked around and can't seem to find a method that is intuitive and doesn't seem like going way out of our way to accomplish something simple.

Comment: Please provide some code snippets with the specific tables and tasks that the code needs to support.

Comment: Thanks, Phil! I'm actually looking to get some high level direction before digging in to anything that would produce a code snippet. Simple put, Copy a section of MS Excel and paste it into an application. Then use one of those columns as a key to update records in a SQL Server DB.

Comment: I`m sorry, I didn't get that, your problem is just to add a few comments to db at one post request? or what? as i can see from tag your orm is ef core? are you parse exel list first and then you try to add comments? do you have these comments as some list already?  maybe smth like http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/entityframework6/addrange-removerange.aspx will be helpful?